# Html drop-down. Different style list if only single element

Tags: php, html, prestashop

How i can change style for SELECT element if list contain only single element?

I have:

```
<select class="attribute_select">
<option selected="selected">001</option>
<option>002</option>
</select>
```

I need:

```
<select class="attribute_select_single">
<option selected="selected">001</option>
</select>
```

Update

```
<select name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" class="attribute_select" onchange="findCombination();getProductAttribute();">
{foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
<option value="{$id_attribute|intval}"{if (isset($smarty.get.$groupName) && $smarty.get.$groupName|intval == $id_attribute) || $group.default == $id_attribute} selected="selected"{/if} title="{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</option>
{/foreach}
</select>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: How i can check single element or not? My example is result html. My lists creating in php.

Comment: You need to show the PHP code that creates the dropdown.

Comment: It's CMS Prestashop. List of attributes. I want check if attribute single, select view basic element, if more single view drop down list

Comment: Your update isn't really usefull @user2849166

Comment: @user2849166 I don't really understand what's the problem, can you be more detailed?
For what I get here, I could suggest you to create 2 distinct html blocks to show based on $group.attributes count. But I'm not sure I really understood the question.

Comment: Let me explain. This product can have multiple attribute values. For example, a monitor with different diagonals. In this case, I have formed a regular drop-down list with values ​​(10'', 20''). If this monitor has only one value of the attribute (10''), it turns out that the drop-down list contains only one item. In this case, the class must be assigned to this element, which would have cleaned the down arrow and frame, thus turning the drop-down list in the regular line.

Comment: Not for ads. http://nubblestore.com/en/bow-tie/18-iphiclides-bow-tie.html. See OPTIONS & FEATUARES, left column, HARDWARE. This list contain single element - Metallic slider.

Comment: Hi your question is if only one item class must be attribute_select_single else if multiples that should be attribute_select right?

Comment: Yes. This is what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery by changing the class of the SELECT element:

```
$(function() {    
  if ($('select.attribute_select option').length == 1)
    $('select.attribute_select').attr('class', 'attribute_select_single');
}
```

You can do it in the template as well with the @count modifier:

replace:

```
class="attribute_select"
```

with:

```
class="{if $group.attributes|@count eq 1}attribute_select_single{else}attribute_select{/if}"
```

Comment: Tnx. The best solution.